# Accessing validation property outside the current scope in vuelidate/VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

Given the following component in Vue 2 using `vuelidate` from property validation:

```html
<template>
  // template stuff here...
</template>

<script>
import { validationMixin } from "vuelidate";
import { required, requiredIf } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
  name: "ParentComponent",
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  data() {
    return {
      selected: false,
      user: {
        email: null,
        password: null,
      },
    };
  },
  validations: {
    selected: { required },
    user: {
      email: { required: requiredIf((vm) => vm.selected) },
      password: { required: requiredIf((vm) => vm.selected) },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The properties `user.email` and `user.password` are required, but only if the validation for `selected` passes successfully. However, this approach does not seem to work, probably because `selected` is not part of the `user` validation object.

Is there a way to access this validation property? Something like this...

```
 validations: {
    selected: { required },
    user: {
      email: { required: requiredIf((vm) => vm.$parentVm.selected) },
      password: { required: requiredIf((vm) => vm.$parentVm.selected) },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like that. Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/green-darkness-90fjs.
`requiredIf` good solution for resolve this problem